# How to query Global Address Book?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I wanted to understand if there is a feature like 'global address book' in lotus notes. If so, is there a way to view all the contacts in a dialog in web browser similar to something like address picker.

Comment: Did you mean as an XPage custom control (as Perr Henrik Lausten supplies) or by other means ?

Comment: @user2808054 Actually I was looking for something by other means and not an extension library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `xe:namepicker` (and attach it to e.g.a `xe:djextNameTextBox`).

Example:

```
<xe:djextNameTextBox id="nameField" value="#{document.nameField}" multipleTrim="true" multipleSeparator=","></xe:djextNameTextBox>
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="nameField">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookSel="all-public" nameList="peopleAndGroups">
        </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of web dialogue boxes developed already - well, there are (I've seen loads)   Trouble is people might have developed something then not published it on the internet.

Unless you're using XPages I don't believe there's anything built-in for web.

I found this :
[Brownie's Blog](http://www.browniesblog.com/A55CBC/blog.nsf/dx/07122009183645MBRAXK.htm?opendocument&comments)
 which looks like it does the trick.

re the address book itslef ..
Unless the admin has changed things, it's fundamentally the view $People or "People" in the database Names.nsf (top level dir of server). This lists all people who have an account on the server, web or Notes. Tis the Name and Address Book = NAB.

Obviously in a large organisation this can be zillions of people so you probably don't want to try showing the whole view hence the name picker